# ASP.net, C# Page load on lightbox close issue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, sql-server

I want to know what exact events fires when ASP.NET page load event fires. As i am using a lightbox in which some insertion is going on and after insertion i want that the parent page reloads with the new value loaded in gridview which i have in parent page. In light box page i added javascript event of parent window reload but sometime it works sometimes it reloads but after refresh newly insert values shows, please help me what i am doing wrong thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have isPostBack check in parent page. Try to remove it for test. 
here is asp.net page lifecircle
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand your question. Am I right in thinking that you are calling `window.location.reload()` in javascript but when the window reloads, the new inserted content isn't always there?

It sounds like you either have a caching issue or you need to insert a brief wait interval before you reload the page. Does this help you?